# MySQL - Which options in the configuration file have an impact on memory usage?

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, memory

I've been wondering how to manage MySQL memory usage since by default it takes up to 350MB while idle on my machine, I don't have memory issues, I honestly just wondered how could it be done.

I found multiple answers about tweaking the configuration file, they worked as intended, one of them even reduced the memory usage down to 100MB.

---

**Questions**

**1.-** Which of the options affect memory usage the most?

**2.-** Where can I learn about the performance impact of these options? (documentation / books / anything)

---

**Sample configuration file, MySQL takes only 100MB** (its a Docker container)

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = 0
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv = NULL
skip-external-locking
max_connections = 100
connect_timeout = 5
wait_timeout = 600
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_cache_size = 128
sort_buffer_size = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size = 128M
table_open_cache = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert = 2
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
long_query_time = 10
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_open_files = 400
innodb_io_capacity = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 16M
```

Comment: start by reading [How MySQL Uses Memory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html)

Comment: general advise - don't try to squeeze memory so tight.

Comment: @danblack Thank you, no I won't, it was merely curiosity on how it works

Answer (score 0):

You need some drastic trimming.

```
max_connections = 100  --> 20
max_allowed_packet = 16M  -->  8M
thread_cache_size = 128  -->  4
sort_buffer_size = 4M  -->  2M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M  -->  2M
tmp_table_size = 32M  -->  4M
max_heap_table_size = 32M  -->  same as tmp_table_size
key_buffer_size = 128M   --> 10M if not using MyISAM; else 20M
table_open_cache = 400   --> 200
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M  --> 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M   -->  4M
innodb_open_files = 400 --> 200

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M -- Hard to say; this may be too low.
```

And, if possible, set up some swap space in case these are not low enough.  Swapping is terrible for performance.

Lowering will lead to slowdown; mostly these are "caches":

```
*buffer*
*open*
*cache
```

Lowering these by too much will lead to some form of error:

```
max_connections
*_size
```

If it is names *_size and it is in MB, then it is probably bytes.  Other *_size tend to be "how many"; I don't know how big each one is (eg, table_open_cache)

The settings in your list that I did not highlight here do not impact memory usage.  The hundreds of other settings are probably no critical for this discussion.

If you would like a more detailed critique, follow the instructions here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning